# How to upload 1hr video to YouTube from fcpx

Tags: video-quality, final-cut-pro-x, youtube

What is best way to upload longer (1hr plus) videos to youtube from fcpx. Currently my fcpx compresses a 1 hr video to 4.5GB and this takes 7000min to upload....

Answer (score 2):

The upload speed to YouTube depends mainly on your Internet connection and has nothing to do with your editing software...

What you can do (if you can't get a better internet connectivity) is to create a smaller file by using higher compression settings.

I don't know how fcpx handles this process, what video format your clip is etc. But you can achieve decent results by compressing a clip to h264 with a bitrate of 10000-15000kbps and then uploading it...

EDIT: As Michael points out thats the Bitrate you are already using. So you need tackle this task from another angle: what is an acceptable upload time for you and what expectations do you have for the quality of the video? And maybe, video technology unrelated: why is your upload speed so slow (and do you have access to a faster connection)...

Then you need to find a compromise between these parameters (video quality vs time needed for upload). You can get a better compromise between file size and upload time by using a more efficient codec like VP9 or h265 which will lead to the same visual result at lower file sizes. This, at least in the case of h265 comes with the "cost" of having much longer compression times. Another option is not using FullHD resolution and just 720p and lowering the bitrate to 5-8000 KBits

Alternatively, export the video with the settings you have now, copy it to a thumb drive and go to a place that has better Internet connectivity for uploading.

Comment: Knowing that there are 3600 seconds in an hour, and that there are 8 bits in a byte, the compressed size (in MB) of a 1hr video is 3600/8 = 450 times the bitrate.  Thus, an hour-long video @ 10000 kbps = 4.5M KB = 4.5 GB.

Comment: Good point, but more helpful would have been using the math skills to calculate the speed of his Internet connection which seems like mid 90's slow :)

Answer (score 1):

I routinely upload videos of an hour or more to YouTube and Vimeo and have found that although FCPX is my editor of choice, it can't handle web uploads as easily as you would hope. For our long shows, it has been proven easier to export a master ProRes file for archiving purposes and then dropping that file into Adobe Media Encoder for further processing. Not only is it faster, you end up with a manageable file size that will look just as good as your 4.5 GB file at a fraction of the size. It will also upload much faster.